# Chart js options not changing chart

Tags: chart.js

I have `chart js` bar chart that displays data correcly however I have two formatting problems that I can't seem to solve:

I want all x-axis labels fixed to be at 90 degrees to the axis (not horizontal or utilising auto rotation) and I want the colour of the bars to be green. I have followed the docs but for some reason I don't get the desired outcome.

```
    var barChartData = {
        labels: ['label 3', 'label 3', 'label 3'],
        datasets: [{
            fillColor: "rgba(0, 255, 0, 1.0)", 
            data: ["1", "2", "3"]
        }]
    };

var ctx2 = document.getElementById("allStudentsProg8").getContext("2d");
var myBar = new Chart(ctx2, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: barChartData,
    options: {
        elements: {
            rectangle: {
                borderWidth: 2,
                borderSkipped: 'bottom'
            }
        },
        responsive: true,
        legend: {
            display: false,
        },
        scales: {
            xAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    minRotation: 90
                }
            }]
        }
    }
});
```

However this is what I get:

[image]

Any pointers as to what I am doing wrong greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ChartJS v2.0

Change next:

> Color

```
         datasets: [{
            fillColor: "rgba(0, 255, 0, 1.0)",
            data: ["1", "2", "3"]
        }]
```

to

```
         datasets: [{
            backgroundColor: "rgba(0, 255, 0, 1.0)",
            borderColor: "#000",
            data: ["1", "2", "3"]
        }]
```

> Rotation of lables

```
            xAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    minRotation: 90
                }
            }]
```

to

```
            xAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    maxRotation: 0, //Do not change ticks width. Or increase              if you need to change also ticks.
                },
                afterCalculateTickRotation : function (self) {
                    self.labelRotation = 90; //Or any other rotation of x-labels you need.
                }
            }]
```

[image: Manual labels rotation ChartJS v2.0]

Comment: Thanks for your help. The colours work but the label rotation doesn't. Does it matter that I am on v2.0?

Comment: Still not working for me - very strange. When I enter your new answer I get them all horizontal.

Comment: @RGriffiths, sorry i've missed method location, check now. I moved it out of **ticks**. This is right variant now :)

Comment: Got there in the end. Superb! Thank you so much.